# I have a code that has to make me able to move a 2d gameobject with a finger touch but it does not work, how can i fix it?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, raycasting

i want to make a 2d gameobject tagged "paddle" follow my finger around the screen only if i touched it first but nothing happens it just stands still.

```
void Update()
{
    // detect if there was a touch
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        switch (touch.phase)
        {
            //When a touch begins:
            case TouchPhase.Began:
                //get the position of the touch
                touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
                touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
                //detect if the touch is on the paddle at the beginning of the touch (if YES then we can move the paddle)
                touchHit = Physics2D.Raycast(touchPosition, Camera.main.transform.forward);
                if (touchHit.collider.tag == "paddle")
                {
                    paddleTouched = true;
                }
                break;
            //When the touch is moving, if it has hit the paddle at the beginning the paddle will move
            case TouchPhase.Moved:
                if (paddleTouched == true)
                {
                    gameObject.transform.position = touchPosition;
                }
                break;
            //When a touch has ended everything ends :3       
            case TouchPhase.Ended:
                paddleTouched = false;
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: then it suggests it never feels the TouchPhase.Moved is valid

Answer (score 0):

I should've put these

```
touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
```

before the switch case statements.